# How to remove some instance or class attributes from __dict__ from dataclasses in Python?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have a class like this one, I use dataclass because I want to store some data and return it simply but I don't want the `__dict__` function to return each attributes.

```
@dataclass
class VCP:
    voltage: float | None = None
    current: float | None = None
    power: float | None = None
    meta: dict | None = None
```

When I do :

```
>>> vcp = VPC()
>>> vcp.__dict__

{"voltage": 15.0, "current": 10.0, "power": 45, "meta": {"time" :15}}
```

What I want to have is :

```
{"voltage": 15.0, "current": 10.0, "power": 45}
```

I already write a solution but overwriting the dict but maybe there is a way to specify that an attribute must not be in `__dict__`

I already write a solution but overwriting the dict but maybe there is a way to specify that an attribute must not be in `__dict__`

Comment: `VCP` doesn't have a `dict` method to begin with. If you are writing it, then have it return whatever you want (or don't want).

Comment: Do you mean `print(vcp.__dict__)`?

Comment: Indeed, `AttributeError: 'VCP' object has no attribute 'dict'`. Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__dict__` is an implementation detail of a class, not really part of its public interface. You don't really want `__dict__` itself: you want *a* dictionary containing a select set of attributes. You can define those attribute via *fields*, and define other attributes via other means.

The function `dataclasses.asdict` will produce a `dict` containing the value of *fields*, not necessarily every instance attribute. For example,

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, InitVar


@dataclass
class VCP:
    voltage: float | None = None
    current: float | None = None
    power: float | None = None
    meta: InitVar[dict | None] = None

    def __post_init__(self, meta):
        self.meta = meta
```

`voltage`, `current`, and `power` are all fields defined by the `dataclass` decorator. `meta` is only an `InitVar`, used to indicate an additional argument to be passed to the generated `__init__` method and passed on to `__post_init__`, if defined.

Then

```
>>> vcp = VCP(15.0, 10.0, 45, {"time": 15})
>>> dataclasses.asdict(vcp)
{'voltage': 15.0, 'current': 10.0, 'power': 45}
>>> vcp.meta
{'time': 15}
```

Because `meta` is not a field, it is not included in the `dict` produced by `asdict`.

Note that other generated methods only operate on fields as well: given this definition, for example, `VCP.__eq__` will not take the value of `meta` into account when determining if two instances of `VCP` are equal.

Answer (score 0):

`__dict__` is not a function or an specific thing for dataclasses: it is a natural property of most Python classes which happens to hold the attribute values for an instance.

The official function to convert a dataclass instance into a dictionary is the `dataclasses.asdict(...)` - but neither have an out-of-the-box way to mark an attribute so that it is not rendered in the result.

The easier way around is to have a base class that can make use of an extra attribute so that it knows which attributes to exclude from the rendering. Normal O.O.P. can do that -
it might only be convenient to have your method starting with a single underline just for the effect of separating it from regular data attributes:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

class Base:
     _exclude = None
     def _asdict(self):
         res = asdict(self)
         if self._exclude:
             for attr in self._exclude:
                 res.pop(attr, None)
         return res 

@dataclass
class VCP(Base):
    voltage: float | None = None
    current: float | None = None
    power: float | None = None
    meta: dict | None = None
    _exclude = ["meta",]
```

And from here on, you just have to call `instance._asdict()` on instances of `VCP` to have the desired data.

I like OOP and I'd use this design. One might prefer to use the API of `dataclasses.asdict` which allows for a custom dict factory: so you might have a function that would create the full dictionary and then exclude the fields that should be left appart, and use instead `dataclasses.asdict(myinstance, dict_factory=attribute_excluder)` - but one would have to remember which dict_factory to use in each call - I think having the method in the instance itself will be more convenient.

Comment: Nit: `asdict` only includes values of defined *fields* (defined using `dataclasses.field`, implicitly like in the `VCP` example shown, etc), not just any instance attribute.

Comment: yes, it will leave `_excludes` out - but the fields defined with annotations in the class body are included. (otherwise, since the use of `dataclasses.Field` is optional, asdict would be mostly useless)

Comment: Not really; there are other ways to define instance attributes in a dataclass than via fields.